# Customizable notebook printing?

Tags: printing, handwriting, paper

I have only been able to find lined notebooks with big spacing between the lines (8mm). I would like to have very tiny spacing (3 or even 2mm). I haven't been able to find them.

Also, I'd like to design my own notebooks with custom layout, so basically I'd like to be able to get a custom notebook with an arbitrary greyscale basis (whether lined, or with e.g. some text in the corner). To be clear I am talking about this being on all the pages of the notebook, not just the cover.

Is there a good online store that will print notebooks based on your custom design? (In the UK)

Answer (score 2):

There are print-on-demand publishers, like Create Space, Lulu, and Lightning Source, that will print just about anything you want. You have to meet requirements like the page size has to be chosen from a list of acceptable sizes, they typically have only a couple of choices for type of paper, etc. But something like "a book made up of pages that are basically blank except that they have lines with this spacing" etc, if you can create a PDF file with pages that look like you want, they'll print it.

I carry a pocket calendar with appointments and phone numbers. I used to struggle every year searching every office supply store in town to find one with a format that I liked -- and of course the fact that a certain store had the format I liked last year does mean they have it again this year. Finally I said, forget this. I wrote a little program to create a calendar in exactly the format that I want, and every year I pay Create Space I think it's $7 to print 2 copies for me.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking it up. Create space is meant for publishing books to a wider audience right? is it helpful for single purchases like this? Is it easy to upload and order a print of a new design quickly?

Comment: I suppose that most people use Create Space (and Lulu) for publishing a book for a general audience. But there's nothing to prevent you from using them to print just a handful of copies. I don't know if they "don't like it" when people do this, but I've been doing this for years with my calendar and they've never said anything to me about it or refused to print my 2 copies. I create a PDF, upload it, and then there's a procedure to "order proof copies", which is what I do. I think it takes maybe 2 weeks for them to print and ship them. You can pay extra for rush handling but I never have.

Comment: I understand that lots of users of Create Space use it to print just a handful of copies, like write up a family history and print 20 copies to send to family members. I had a conversation once with someone who used Create Space to print some book of company policies for his small business and printed 20 or 30 copies for his employees. Etc. So 2 copies is surely an extreme, but it's not like they expect the typical client to print thousands. Somewhere or other I read that the average is like 200 copies.

Answer (score 1):

I had a friend in University who wanted this and he did it using Publisher (which Microsoft will give for free to students at least in Canada and the USA). He then took it to the University Printer (student run, good quality and fair prices). There he had them do it up on campus.

Maybe your school has a similar shop?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://paperkit.net/linedpaper. You can set your own line height and then download it as a PDF template. I didn't play with it to see sizing variety and paper size options but you might be able to get what you want there and it is free.